# How to pass nodejs the --harmony flag in elastic bean stalk

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

My nodejs application which is running in Elastic Bean Stalk is using ECMA6 so I need to pass node the --harmony flag for it to work. Is there a configuration page or file in elastic bean stalk that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `npm start` and changed my package.json to look like

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node --harmony server.js",
},
```